# Need Stacktrace error logs from Debug Android App without Google Play

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I need the Error logs with stack trace from my users with my Android App (Debug, deployed via DeployGate). I've tried DeployGate SDK and RemoteLogCat. RemoteLogCat and DeployGate only send Log messages that I've put in myself, but I need the current LogCat data (as if it would be hooked up to my own PC) with LogLevel "Error".

This is what I need:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: www.myapp.nl.simpelfragmentvoorbeeld, PID: 5020 
java.lang.RuntimeException: NullPointerException
at www.myapp.nl.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at    
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.
run(ZygoteInit.java:1389) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

Many thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried ACRA?

Comment: @malrok44 thnx! This is perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

*ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form. It is targetted to android applications developers to help them get data from their applications when they crash or behave erroneously.*